# String comparison VBA

Tags: excel, string-comparison, vba

I am trying to complete a string comparison between a range and the cells to the left of it. So it goes through a range, looks at a cell, takes the value to the right and compares them. The end goal being to populate an array with all the values that match.

The issue I am having is when I use debug.print, the string's do seem to match. However the StrComp evaluation i am using is evaluating to false.

```
Sub FilterProdType()
'Get the product filter chosen and set to a variable
Dim bArray As Variant
Dim search, cell As Range
Dim prod, item As String
Set search = Sheet2.Range("B2:B41")


For Each cell In search
    prod = Sheet1.Range("PRODTYPE").Value
    item = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Debug.Print ("Value in range 'B2:B41':" & prod)
    Debug.Print ("Value in cell directly left one column:" & item)
    MsgBox StrComp(item, prod) = 0
Next cell
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `If item Like prod Then`

Comment: Have you tried `, CompareMethod.Text` or `Binary` after the `item, prod`? It might be that you just need to set the compare method. Also check if there are any additional spaces as they might cause it to return false

Comment: have you tried the old but gold item = prod ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me that you are comparing a `item` as `String` with a `prod` as `Variant`, because you did a confusion in your variables declaration.

Would you add

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top, would you see that your code requires

```
Dim search As Range, cell As Range
Dim prod As String, item As String
```

... This is Excel-VBA, not VB.

Hope it helps.